# HTML5 single deviceorentationevent and devicemotionevent which are null

Tags: javascript, android, html, null, device-orientation

I'm trying to use Chrome (version 44) HTML5 device orientation events. I've tried this on 2 different android tablets and my Windows laptop. On my laptop, I set a breakpoint for events but I only 2 events (1 for each type) and they do contain nulls. What can I do to diagnose this problem? Do I need to enable something?

output:

```
DeviceOrientationEvent available
Alpha: null Beta: null Gamma: null
```

is generated by the following HTML on both tablets and Windows PC:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><div id="output"></div><div id="output2"></div>
<script>
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "DeviceOrientationEvent available";
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(event) {
    document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "Alpha: " + event.alpha + "Beta: " + event.beta + "Gamma: " + event.gamma;
    }, false);
} else {
    document.getElementById("outputO").innerHTML = "DeviceOrientationEvent not available";
}
</script></body></html>
```

Thanks for any advice or suggestions.

Comment: What you are doing seems correct. It is possible that your browsers do not add support for the alpha/beta/gamma properties (the specification is 'non-normative'), although this seem unlikely given they are supporting DeviceOrientation anyway.

Comment: Apparently these are null if the device does not support them, but one would expect it to on a tablet. The DeviceOrientation specification is still relatively new, so maybe the device just doesn't properly implement it yet. Can you test whether alpha/beta/gamma are defined or not?

Comment: The android tablets support device orientation because I've installed a carpenters level on it. Without device orientation,, it could not work as a level. Since google has tight control over android and chrome, this should work for any device where a carpenters level works correctly.  As for the alpha/beta/gamma, they are part of the class definition so they default to null. I used chrome debug to look at the events and those variables show as null. Has anyone got this working on an android tablet using Chrome? If so, did you do anything special to enable it?